# git contribution global email

Tags: git, github

In the meantime, I haven't set up a global name and email.

And I did a git push.

Therefore, it was not shown in the contribution.

I just found out.

I just set up a global email and name.

Is there a way to display the content pushed so far in the contribution?

Comment: `git push` does not use `user.name`, nor `user.email`. So the lack of a name and email had no effect whatsoever on your `git push`. It does have an effect on `git commit`, because `git commit` must supply a name-and-email-address for the commit metadata, but it has no effect on `git push`. To display the name and email address in a commit, use `git show` on the commit, perhaps with `--pretty=fuller` to show both author and committer.

Comment: Meanwhile, GitHub contribution information is an entirely different thing. It does use the information in the author and committer fields of each commit, but it runs that information through translations that you supply outside of Git entirely. Contribution information is updated on a periodic basis, not always instantly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to display them , because the email address used for a commit should be associated with you git-hub account. if you email address used for the commits not connected to your account on GitHub.com you must add the email address to your account on GitHub.com. Your contributions graph will be rebuilt automatically when you add the new address. but unfortunately  you can't edit or add an email to you old commits.
for more : https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile