# Recover past contributions on git that did not have a correct mail linked

Tags: r, git

This issue is related with my contributions to a specific project that I have invested quite a bit of time on git.

I have linked my mail on git with my global options and now the commits are recognized. However, what I'm afraid is that I cannot recover my past contributions which are a lot.

I have seen several answers with this related topic but no clear answers of how to assign the past contributions to my account that that did not have a verified mail associated and just a local one for what it seems surname@name-MacBook-Pro.local. Is it possible?

These are two related answers but they didn't help me to solve it (one of them says that is not possible):

[git contribution global email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68319882/git-contribution-global-email)
[Git contributions not showing up on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136844/git-contributions-not-showing-up-on-github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you can replace the associated email in each commit.

See this answer for a script that will do exactly this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34851024

Note that you will then need to force push: `git push -f`
But also note that this may cause issues for other people if they cloned your project.

Comment: It worked! I was missing this "git push -f" Thanks a lot! Still not appearing as contributor but this may be because this takes some time. All my commits appear now :)